# Waiting with observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a function `f` supplied to a `concatMap` inside a `pipe` chain.

I would like `f` to have a retry capability after a wait.

```
const f = () => somethingIsTrue 
  ? Observable.create(() => /* ... */) 
  : /* invoke `f` after waiting one second */
```

How can I wait and retry `f` after waiting one second?

Comment: You can use `repeatWhen(timer(1000))` to resubscribe after 1s.